# Counting adjacent duplicates in scheme and prolog

Tags: prolog, scheme

I am new to scheme and prolog and have done only a few basic problems.
I need to write a function in scheme and prolog for counting adjacent recurrences in a list.

Example: `(Count '(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1))` gives `((3 1) (1 2) (2 3) (1 1))`

I do not want the code as this is homework but any hints or how to think about this problem would be appreciated as I don't know where to start.

Comment: Solve the (trivial) problem for lists of length 0 and 1.
Then solve the case with two identical numbers at the head of the list by recursion.
Finally, solve the case with two non-identical numbers at the head.
You might need a cut to prune prolog's search tree (i.e. keep it from finding more solutions after the first one).

Comment: “I need to write a function in scheme and prolog...”. In Prolog you write predicates, not functions!

Comment: This is called "run length encoding" maybe you have better luck with searching?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a hypothetical function `loop`:

(loop todo done)

that rewrites the list in `todo` to you wanted format 
and `done` contains the part already handled.

```
(loop '(1 1 1 2 3 3 1) '())
(loop   '(1 1 2 3 3 1) '((1 1))
(loop     '(1 2 3 3 1) '((1 2))
(loop       '(2 3 3 1) '((1 3))
(loop         '(3 3 1) '((2 1) (1 3))
(loop           '(3 1) '((3 1) (2 1) (1 3))
(loop             '(1) '((3 2) (2 1) (1 3))
(loop              '() '((1 1) (3 2) (2 1) (1 3))
'((1 1) (3 2) (2 1) (1 3)
```

Given such a function `loop` you can write

```
(define (count xs) 
    (reverse loop xs '())
```

Now in order to implement `loop` you need to consider these cases:

```
1) todo is empty
2) done is empty
3) the first element of todo is different from the first element of done
3) the first element of todo is the same as the first element of done
```

Comment: `(define (loop lst)(let((x 0)))
(cond ((null? lst) '())
((null? cdr lst)((+ x 1)(cons x car lst)))
((eq? (car lst)(cadr lst))((+ x 1)(cons x car lst)(loop cddr lst)))
((not(eq? (car lst)(cdr lst)))(loop lst))))`